# show a reactive value for textInput from a .csv in a shinyapp

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, reactive

I am developing a shinyapp for producing interactively a table with the names of files and some new text or comment for each one.
Currently it works by following this steps:
1. selecting a folder
2. creating a .csv with the names of files (if none)
The name of the .csv follows the pattern "subfolderName".csv
3. Selecting a filename with the selectInput option
4. adding your comments for each row (file) to the .csv file in the
second column named "comments"

Some desired behaviour I couldn't do:
- Show the previous comment, if any, for the current selected filename (saved in the .csv), in the text field (commentwritten). I tried also updateTextInput and didn't work.

```
#save as app.R
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(shinyBS)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    shinyDirButton("dir", "1. Choose directory", "Upload")
    ,br(),br()
    ,  bsButton("submit","2. Create or reset .csv", style="warning")
    ,br(),br()
    , uiOutput("fileinput")
    , uiOutput("uitextinput") # this is not showing existing comments

    ,  bsButton("addname","4. Add comment", style="warning")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h4("Selected folder"),
    verbatimTextOutput("dirtext"), br(),
    h4("Files in that dir"),
    verbatimTextOutput("files"),
    textOutput("result")
  )
)) 

path1<-"~"

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$result<-renderText({
    t<- reac$message
  })

  shinyDirChoose(input, 'dir', roots = c(home = path1) )
  reacdir <- reactive(input$dir)
  output$dirtext <- renderPrint(c(path(),current() ) )

  path <- reactive({
    home <- normalizePath(path1)
    file.path(home, paste(unlist(reacdir()$path[-1]), collapse = .Platform$file.sep))
  })

  current<-reactive({
    a<-sub('.*\\/', '', path() )  
    b<-paste("current subdir:",a)
  })

  reac <- reactiveValues(comment=NULL, df2=NULL)

  #not WORKING
  output$uitextinput<-renderUI(
    textInput("commentwritten","Comment for file", reac$comment)
  )

  # GET current .csv file with comments and load the comment to reac$comment , Not working
  observe({
    validate(
      need(try(any(class(reactiveFileReader(1000, session, paste0(path(),"/",sub('.*\\/', '', path() ),".csv") , 
                                            read.csv()))=="data.frame")==TRUE), "Wait 801")
    )       
    reac$df2<-  reactiveFileReader(1000, session, paste0(path(),"/",sub('.*\\/', '', path() ),".csv") , read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    reac$comment<-reac$df2$comment[match(input$file, reac$df2$name)]
  })

  filedata<-reactive({
    filenames<-  list.files(path())
    filedata<-data.frame(name=filenames)
  })

  # button 2. creating the csv file
  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    write.csv(filedata(), file =paste0(path(),"/",sub('.*\\/', '', path() ),".csv")  , row.names = FALSE ) 
  })

  #step 3
  output$fileinput<-renderUI(
    div(style="width: 100%; margin: 0 0;",
        selectInput("file", "3. Select filename to add details", filedata()$name)
    )
  )

  #step 4, adding a comment to the .csv 
  observeEvent(input$addname , {
    if(file.exists(paste0(path(),"/",sub('.*\\/', '', path() ),".csv")) ){
    dfnameadded <- reactive({
      originaldf<-reactiveFileReader(1000, session, paste0(path(),"/",sub('.*\\/', '', path() ),".csv") , read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      filetoadd <- data.frame(name=input$file , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      filetoadd$comment<-input$commentwritten
      l<-list(originaldf(),filetoadd)#
      dfadded<- Reduce(bind_rows, l)
      dfadded<-dfadded %>%
        group_by(name) %>%
        summarise(comment = paste0(na.omit(comment[length(comment)]), collapse = "; ") )
      dfadded
    })
    tryCatch(write.csv(dfnameadded(), file =paste0(path(),"/",sub('.*\\/', '', path() ),".csv")  , row.names = FALSE ), 
             error = function(e) {print(paste("create .csv first")) ; "create .csv first" } )
    reac$message<-"comment added"
    }
    else
    {
    reac$message<-"create .csv first"  
    }
  })

  output$files <- renderPrint(list.files(path()))
} # end server 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: if i understand your question, use ` textInput("namewritten","Comment for photo", placeholder = yourcommentvariable)` for the previous comment to appear as a deletable text in the text field

Comment: I tried that Phi, no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to this solution
Replacing

```
  #not WORKING
  # output$uitextinput<-renderUI(
  #   textInput("commentwritten","Comment for file", reac$comment)
  # )
```

with:

```
  observeEvent(input$file , {
    if(file.exists(paste0(path(),"/",sub('.*\\/', '', path() ),".csv")) ){
      originaldf<-reactiveFileReader(1000, session, paste0(path(),"/",sub('.*\\/', '', path() ),".csv"), read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      reac$df<-originaldf()
      output$uitextinput<-renderUI({          
        textInput("commentwritten","Comment for file",
                  reac$df$comment[match(input$file, reac$df$name)]
        )
      }) 
    }
    else{"index file does not exist, create with button 2."}
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
reac <- reactiveValues(comment <- NULL, df <- NULL)
textInput("namewritten","Comment for photo",placeholder= if(is.null(reac$comment)){"No Comments"}else{reac$comment})
```

also i'd make df a reactiveValue as well. Youre using an observe to basically call a reactive function but the observe isnt going to return any values so reac$comment isnt getting returned.

Comment: i had not success

Comment: Could you please supply a sample of the data youre using so that I can give a complete answer?

Comment: it should work in your system. maybe you have to change path1?